# Understanding the "this" arg in function.apply when you set it to a jQuery set

Tags: javascript, jquery, apply, jquery-validate

I'm trying to wrap my head around Javascript's function.apply().  You use it like this:
`f.apply(obj,args)`

to run function `f` with the given arguments `args`, with the function's internal usage of `this` mapped onto the object `obj`.

Here's a simple example to show how that all works to get us up-to-speed:

```
var o = { 
  state : 0, 
  plus : function(){
    this.state += 1;
  }
}
//o is an object with a state-tracking var and a function that will operate on it
o.state
// 0
o.plus()
o.state
// 1
newO = {state:3}
// newO  is similar to the original object, but doesn't have that state-manipulating function
newO.state
// 3
o.plus.apply(newO,[])  // call o's function, but hijack the 'this' reference to point to newO
newO.state
// 4
```

Cool.  So I've written a function to solve a null pointer issue in javascript with a particular jquery plugin.  If a jQuery set is empty, it just doesn't run a function:

```
var applyIfPresent = function(jqObj,func,args){
  //only works if jquery has the func you supply
  if(jqObj.length){
    jqObj[func].apply(jqObj,args);
  }
}
```

I've run the simple test: `applyIfPresent($("input"),"css",["background","blue"]);`
To see if it'll generalize to a jQuery set of multiple elements. It seems to work fine, but I have no idea how the internals of jQuery and the usage of `this` translates to that schema.  I love that it seems to work like magic, but honestly?--I've learned to be a little afraid of magic.

How does f.apply or jQuery figure all that out to make it work?

Comment: The [source for jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) is available. I'm not quite sure what the question is, as it (`Function.apply`) is just "standard" JavaScript...

Comment: You seem to know how `apply` works, and you seem to know how to use jQuery's API.  I guess it's not clear what actually is confusing you.  Your `applyIfPresent()` function there would work on any object with a `length` property, jQuery or not.

Comment: Are you aware that if `length` is zero, jQuery methods are a no-op? I.e. `applyIfPresent($("input"), "css", ["background", "blue"])` does the EXACT SAME THING as `$("input").css("background", "blue")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not that magic, you seem to understand it perfectly by the example above.
when you do

```
jqObj[func].apply(jqObj,args);
```

it's basically the same as doing

```
$(jqObj).func(args);
```

Answer (score 2):

`.apply()` isn't a JQuery feature, it's a core JavaScript language feature. You likely won't find anything useful in the JQuery source in regards to this since they didn't invent the wheel here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply